# Как правильно настроить Annotation Audited hibernate?

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Есть `класс UBaseFace` содержащий entity-класс `Persona` (табл. `persona`).
В entity-классе `Persona` есть поле `type`, которое принимает  enum-значение.
Как настроить, что бы измененные данные хранились в табличке аудита.
Я использую `Annotation Audited hibernate`.
Но у меня при записи/изменении данных в табличке `persona_aud`, почему то не заполняются данные в поле `type`. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Класc `UBaseFace`:

```
 public class UBaseFace() { ...
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
     @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
     @AuditJoinTable(name="persona_aud")
     @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
     public Set<Persona> getPersona() {...}

  }
```

Класс `Persona`:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "persona") 
public class Persona() { 
//...
     private long id;
     private PersonaType type;

     //get/set для обоих полей 
}
```